# proguard obfuscate with mapping file in EE project

Tags: proguard, obfuscation

I am using proguard to obfuscate my java project. Now i have successfully obfuscated the jar file and added into project build path.

But it shows some of the referenced class/objects not mapped properly, since the jar file class name is like A, B, C etc..,

In proguard a mapping file was generated, but i couldn't trace the class name properly because the class names are changed to different.

Please suggest how to map the project with the obfuscated jar file using the mapping file..

There was no tutorial/references found for mapping the project with the mapping file using proguard in Web.

Thanks in advance for your suggestion..

Comment: What is your actual problem? Are you unable to deobfuscate stacktraces using the mapping.txt file produced by Proguard? If so, how did you perform the obfuscation? What build system/script/console command did you use? Please post the steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have a mapping file and Jar generated from proguard. How i need to use the jar in my existing project, since the jar is obfuscated. The reference are not mapped properly..